# SML: How to determine if a list index is empty?

Tags: list, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I'm trying to determine if my hd(tl list) is nothing or not. `hd(tl list) = ?` What would I use on the other side of the equality symbol?

Comment: You could just compare `tl list` with `[]`:  `tl list = []`

Comment: What do you mean by "list index is empty"?

Comment: @John Coleman Thank you! That worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express the question 'is `hd(tl list)` nothing or not' as the equivalent question, 'does the `list` have less than two elements'. The latter question is easy to answer with SML in an elegant way using pattern matching on the list. Here is an interactive session:

```
$ poly
Poly/ML 5.7.1 Release
> fun isNothing [] = true
#   | isNothing [_] = true
#   | isNothing _ = false;
val isNothing = fn: 'a list -> bool
```

This function is saying, 'an empty list evaluates to `true`', 'a list with a single element evaluates to `true`', any other list evaluates to `false`. Tests:

```
> isNothing [];
val it = true: bool
> isNothing [1];
val it = true: bool
> isNothing [1, 2];
val it = false: bool
> isNothing [1, 2, 3];
val it = false: bool
```